# concat two dataframe with joint axis

Tags: python, pandas

i thought this would be very simple but i cannot make it work...
I have 2 dataframes:

```
    fpeaklocs
    Out[203]: 
       Hz
    0   6
    1  15
    2  21
    3  28
    4  11

    fpeakvals
    Out[204]: 
              A
    0 -0.000426
    1  0.000362
    2  0.000420
    3  0.000377
    4  0.000420
```

I just want it to be:

```
     Hz         A
0   6.0 -0.000426
1  15.0  0.000362
2  21.0  0.000420
3  28.0  0.000377
4  11.0  0.000420
```

But when i try the following, it gives me this:

```
pd.concat([fpeaklocs, fpeakvals], axis=1)
    Out[201]: 
     Hz         A
    0   6.0       NaN
    1  15.0       NaN
    2  21.0       NaN
    3  28.0       NaN
    4  11.0       NaN
    0   NaN -0.000426
    1   NaN  0.000362
    2   NaN  0.000420
    3   NaN  0.000377
    4   NaN  0.000420
```

Any idea how to achieve what i want?

There are more observations:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Hz':fpeaklocs, 'A':fpeakvals}, index=fpeakvals.index)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 5)

fpeaklocs.join(fpeakvals)
Out[246]: 
   Hz   A
0   6 NaN
1  15 NaN
2  21 NaN
3  28 NaN
4  11 NaN
```

Comment: You want “join” not concat.

Comment: fpeaklocs.join(fpeakvals) shows 0 to 4 row of my last code....col 'A' remains NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `pd.concat` should produce your expected output, and it works in my tests. Try the following to ensure that the indexes of both DataFrames line up, then re-run your `concat` line, or use `join`:

```
fpeaklocs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
fpeakvals.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

After that, either of the following should work:

```
pd.concat([fpeaklocs, fpeakvals], axis=1)
```

or

```
fpeaklocs.join(fpeakvals)
```

If that still doesn't work, try this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Hz':fpeaklocs.values.flatten(), 'A':fpeakvals.values.flatten()})
```

Thanks to Peter's suggestion, the merge is finally working:

```
fpeaklocs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
fpeakvals.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
pd.concat([fpeaklocs, fpeakvals], axis=1)
```

And the .index result of these two datadrames was like this:

```
fpeaklocs.index
Out[250]: Index(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='object')

fpeakvals.index
Out[251]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

So the problem was coming from fpeaklocs, and after the reset_index():

```
fpeaklocs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

fpeaklocs.index
Out[254]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

Thank you all!

Comment: wow, the reset_index() make it works. Great thanks.
any chance if u can tell me when this would be necessary. 
seem it is not obvious why some(or my) dataframes needs to reset_index()

Comment: @Simon, my only guess is that the `Index` of one or both DataFrames does not contain integers, despite what they display as. To figure that out, you can compare the outputs of `fpeaklocs.index` and `fpeakvals.index`. Maybe one of the indexes contains floats, or strings.

Comment: your guess is correct. fpeaklocs' index is string. 
i have updated more findings based on your reply for others.I should update the function to generate these 2 dataframes as well.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Simon, great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> fpeakvals = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': [-0.000426, 0.000362, 0.000420, 0.000377, 0.000420]})
>>> fpeaklocs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Hz': [6, 15, 21, 28, 11]})
>>> 
>>> pd.merge(fpeaklocs, fpeakvals, left_index=True, right_index=True)
   Hz         A
0   6 -0.000426
1  15  0.000362
2  21  0.000420
3  28  0.000377
4  11  0.000420
>>>
```

Comment: it shows Empty DataFrame Columns: [Hz, A]
Index: []

Comment: How did you create the dataframe objects `fpeakvals` and `fpeaklocs`. That might give us some hint on why it is not working for you

Comment: i am not sure I fully understand the code to generate fpeaklocs and fpeakvals...
I have just updated more observations results....
if there is any chance to suggest some ways to check these 2 dataframes? 
i don't understand why dataframe can perform differently.